# Recaptcha causes duplicated form to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, salesforce-lightning

Can someone assist me with the issue I'm facing with the web forms on my landing page? I have added a Salesforce-generated form in the first section, and I duplicated the same form at the bottom of the page. However, only the first form is functioning correctly as it has a Google recaptcha validation associated with it. The second form is not working, and I believe I need to change some IDs to rectify this issue. Can anyone guide me on which IDs need to be changed for the second form to function correctly?

Here is the code:

```
    <script>
    function submitUserForm() {
      var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
      if(response.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '<span>Click the checkbox above to verify that you are not a robot.</span>';
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    function verifyCaptcha() {
      document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
  function timestamp() { var response = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); if (response == null || response.value.trim() == "") {var elems = JSON.parse(document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value);elems["ts"] = JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime());document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value = JSON.stringify(elems); } } setInterval(timestamp, 500);
</script>
<div class="nps-offer-form">
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitUserForm();">
    <input type=hidden name='captcha_settings' value='{"keyname":"V2_Site_Key","fallback":"true","orgId":"00D80000000cpsm","ts":""}'>
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D80000000cpsm">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://google.com">

    <label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required /><br>


    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcfhwokAAAAAKDe6-N1YyU4njEVUPnV8uZY_8bD" data-callback="verifyCaptcha"></div>
    <div id="g-recaptcha-error" class="g-recaptcha-alert"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-30-trial" value="Get 30 Days Free Trial" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, so you should change _all_ IDs that occur anywhere in the code.